# Sort GridView by column populated in RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a GridView which is populated with user information.

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection users = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers();        
grid.DataSource = users;
this.DataBind();
```

In the RowDataBound event, it looks up additional user information and populates columns with this info.

Due to the nature for the GetAllUsers() function, the grid is sorted by username.  I would like for it to sort by FullName, one of the columns that is looked up and populated in the RowDataBound even code.  How can I do this?  Everything I see on sorting for a GridView has you sort the datasource before applying it to the grid, but in this case I do not have that data yet.

Comment: By the time you get to RowDataBound, it's too late. You'll need to rethink how you get the user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort gridview's datasource before data-binding:

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection users = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers();
grid.DataSource = users.OfType<MembershipUser>().OrderBy(GetUserFullName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

private static string GetUserFullName(MembershipUser user)
{
    // return here user's full name
    return user.Email;
}
```

Comment: This may be my best bet b/c there's other stuff going on in that event and to rewrite it all would take too much time for a seemingly simple request for the customer.